# Add to PATH, no ~/.profile nor ~/.pam_environment

Tags: paths

I just compiled ffmpeg, now I just want to add it on the path.

Every source I can find reference .profile, and if not present or in specific cases, tell to use .pam_environment.

But double tab give me:

```
user@domain:~$ echo $HOME
/home/user
user@domain:~$ cd /home/empreinte/
user@domain:~$ nano .
./             .cache/        .local/        .npm/
../            .config/       .nano_history  .ssh/
.bash_history  .dbshell       .node-gyp/
```

Am I missing something? Can I just create the file?

EDIT:

```
user@domain:~$ ls -a $HOME
.              .cache    drywall  .nano_history  npm-debug.log  test   x264
..             .config   ffmpeg   .node-gyp      .ssh           tmp    yasm
.bash_history  .dbshell  .local   .npm           sysplay        video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to copy the default if you don't want to. You can simply create a new, empty `.profile` and add this line there:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/empreinte/
```

Avinash's approach is also correct of course, the files in `/etc/skel` are the defaults and you can copy the template file from there. It is just unnecessary since you can create it yourself.

In any case, I would recommend you create a new folder where you want to keep your own binaries and add *that* to the $PATH instead of keeping `ffmpeg` in your `$HOME`:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ~/ffmpeg ~/bin
```

Then, edit your `~/.profile` and use this line instead of the above:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/empreinte/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Ubuntu Enviroinment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), you could use also `~/.pam_environment`, as you suggested.

So, create file if not exists, or edit if exists, and insert this line:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/path/to/ffmpeg/bin
```

Comment: Don't forget to logout and login to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

A backup of `.profile` file would be present inside `/etc/skel` directory. Try to copy the same file to your HOME directory.

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

#### How i know this information?

```
$ locate .profile
/etc/skel/.profile
/home/avinash/.profile
```